# DNNArticle Module and Multi instance in Dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

one of best module for dnn in news and article is `DNNArticle` . each module instance that putted in the page has its own category and tags. when using `dnnarticle category list` module in its options we have to select only one instance . is it possible to show all category from all instance of DNNArticle.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask the developer on the [Support Page](http://zldnn.com/Support#/)?

Comment: yes ,but all developer from any module , any platform are active in SO . I Asked there before posting to SO . After recieveing answer there i will post it here to help other that have same problem as me.